# Python inheritance, having set_up() method that's always called by base class init while having varying arguments in child classes

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I want to achieve something like this. But python gives error of missing argument resource due to the fact Node calls set_up without argument. What's the correct way to do it?
Basically I want to factor out the initialisation of a class into set_up and at the same time having this set_up method callable when provided with the necessary resources. The child class requires resources that's not required by base, and at the same time the set_up should always called by init as it does the actually initialisation.

--------edit---------

I will try to explain my motivation better. I want to have a set_up method that does the initialisation of Node so I can re-initialise a Node during runtime. And I want to provide certain resources through this set_up in MyNode which aren't required by Node. So the ideal behavior is that

```
MyNode("node", resource="water").name == "node_altered"
MyNode("node", resource="water").resource == "water"
MyNode("node").set_up("water").resource == "water"
MyNode("node").set_up("water").set_up("fire") == "fire" 
MyNode("node").set_up("water").set_up().resource == "water"
```

this is my try:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.set_up()
        
    def set_up(self):
        self.name = name + "_altered"
    
class MyNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, name, resource=None):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.foo = None
        self.resource = resource
        
    def set_up(self, resource):
        super().set_up()
        self.foo = "foo"
        self.resource = resource
        return self
    
MyNode("foo").set_up(2).resource
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-01756d189150> in <module>
     17         return self
     18 
---> 19 MyNode("foo", "resource").set_up(2).resource

<ipython-input-70-01756d189150> in __init__(self, name, resource)
      9 class MyNode(Node):
     10     def __init__(self, name, resource):
---> 11         super().__init__(name)
     12         self.resource = None
     13 

<ipython-input-70-01756d189150> in __init__(self, name)
      2     def __init__(self, name):
      3         self.name = name
----> 4         self.set_up()
      5 
      6     def set_up(self):

TypeError: set_up() missing 1 required positional argument: 'resource'
```

Comment: `self.set_up()` doesn't necessarily call `Node.set_up`; it depends on the *runtime* type of `self`. (This will be the type error you get after fixing the one you are currently asking about.)

Comment: @Carcigenicate i copied the wrong code, updated it

Comment: @chepner ye i updated the question. but how do i correctly do that? when child class requires resources that's not required by base, and at the same time have set_up being called by init always

Comment: If you can't modify `Node` to make `Node.set_up` more general, then you are going to have to define a *different* method that you call either directly or inside `MyNode.__init_`. You can't change the signature if `Node.__init__` is using it with the original signature.

Comment: @chepner i can modify Node actually. The goal is to have a design where end users can create their own set_up requiring varying resources. And these resources are typically not available at Node instantiation time. So it has to be provided later.

Comment: so you want your set_up method to be dynamic? Or have something like two type of constructors?

Comment: Then why is `setup` being called inside `Node.__init__`?  It sounds like the child classes are entirely responsible for defining and calling `set_up`, so it doesn't need to be in `Node` at all.

Comment: @chepner because the setup's behavior should be consistent. When node1 inherits node2 which inherits node, users should have this mental model that each subtype's setup will execute correctly.

Comment: But `Node` *can't* execute `set_up` without knowing how the child is going to define it (unless you explicitly call `Node.set_up(self)` instead, which is pointless because it does nothing.) If you want `Node` to call the method, you need to at least accept arbitrary arguments (`def set_up(self, *args, **kwargs)`), but that doesn't solve the problem of `Node.__init__` not knowing what arguments to pass *to* `set_up` when it calls it.

Comment: @chepner that's exactly the problem i don't know how to properly solve.

Comment: You can't, unless you are passing the necessary arguments to `__init__` in a way that `Node.__init__` knows which ones should be passed to `set_up`.

Comment: What's even supposed to be the point of this `set_up` method? "Basically I want to factor out the initialisation of a class into set_up" doesn't make sense - that's `__init__`'s job. Why not do initialization in `__init__`? (And if you're going to "factor out" `__init__`'s job into `set_up`, why not "factor out" that into a `real_setup` called from `set_up`, and "factor out" that into a `setup_really_i_mean_it_this_time` called from `real_setup`?)

Comment: Your requirements are inconsistent. You've said that `resource` should be a required argument for `set_up`, but you've also used `MyNode("node").set_up("water").set_up().resource == "water"` as an example test case, and that doesn't pass `resource` in the second `set_up` call. Also, `MyNode("node")` has no `resource` value to pass to `set_up`.

Comment: It looks like you may be best served by implementing separate `__init__` and `update` methods, with `__init__` *not* calling `update`. It'd let you separate the call signatures more cleanly and not have to worry about how the base class `__init__` is going to know the right signature for a subclass method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_up(self):
      print(self.name)

    
class MyNode(Node):

    def set_up(self, resource):
      super().set_up()
      self.resource = resource
      return self

    

print(MyNode('bar').set_up('foo').resource)
print('----')
print(MyNode("bar").set_up('bar').resource)
print('----')
print(MyNode("bar").set_up().resource)
```

output

```
bar
foo
----
bar
bar
----
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(MyNode("bar").set_up().resource)
TypeError: set_up() missing 1 required positional argument: 'resource'
```

Edit :

As per OP comment:
What you are trying to achieve is not possible with the way you designed this.
You have to give up at either the mandatory resource in `MyNode` or calling `set_up` from `__init__` because of the method resolution order.
`Node.__init___` will call the set_up and pass arguments to it, now the arguments can be made to be dynamic but you cannot restrict the arguments as when you call the constructor for the first time it will not have the resource parameter and throw an error.
Another solution is to not call `super` in `MyNode.__init__` and `MyNode.set_up` and there handle all the logic there, but then would you even need to inherit from node?!

Comment: MyNode.set_up should have argument resource. And this set_up can be called multiple times as a way to reinitialize MyNode.

Comment: Can the __init__ of MyNode have resource argument?

Comment: Ok, i modified the answer as per your comment, is this the thing you want to do?

Comment: this is very close! i would also like to ask resource to be a mandatory argument since a user is required to provide it at set_up time.

Comment: ok now resource is mandatory. Let me know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: but now set_up is not called by Node.__init__

Comment: Why would Node.__init__ call setup?

Answer (score 0):

Why not define a default `None` value for `MyNode.set_up` as well ?

```
[...]
    [...]
        
    def set_up(self, resource=None):
        if resource is None:
            raise TypeError(
                "set_up() 'resource' argument cannot be None"
            )
            
        super().set_up()
        self.resource = resource
        return self
```

Comment: this will cause error too by Node.__init__ exactly because resource is None